Waltz in e minor by Ferdinando Carulli
I started learning a bit of classical guitar 2 years back. I only learnt and retained this piece, so forgive me for having no music knowledge, and I apologize if my question is ill phrased but are there any key modulations or harmonic surprises in this piece?
I have played this a lot since I learnt it, but I forgot what got me hooked in the first place....I believe there was this catch..but ive forgotten it. I still enjoy it but im afraid I dont appreciate it as much as I should.

The piece has a prominent key change from E minor to G major.
The piece has four sections, each repeated, denoted in the image below as A, B, C, and D. Sections A and B are in E minor, while sections C and D are in G major. After playing all four sections, the piece returns to play parts A and B again. Thus, the overall structure of the piece is E minor — G major — E minor.
Another feature of the piece is that it has multiple "voices" — that is, it's as though three different instruments each has a part. The highest notes make up the melody (blue rectangle), the lowest notes create a bass line (green-circled notes), and the middle notes (orange rectangle) add to the overall harmony, rhythm, and provide a counterpart to the melody.


Yes! It was the three voices. Thankyou so much
